# useSelector() providing initial value instead of updated value?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux along with react-redux and unable to use the useSelector() function to access the updated value.

**Reducer**
Imported the action inside the reducer
Initialised state
Called reducer and initialised the state as initial state
Added a conditional statement which updates the initial state

```
import { UPDATE_EMAIL } from "../actions/cred";

const initialState = {
  phone: "",
  uid: null,
  tp: null,
};

const credReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  // return state;
  if (action.type === UPDATE_EMAIL) {
    return {
      ...state,
      phone: action.phone,
      uid: action.uid,
      tp: action.tp,
    };
  } else {
    return state;
  }
};

export default credReducer;
```

**Action**

```
export const UPDATE_EMAIL = "UPDATE_EMAIL";

export const updateEmail = (id, uid, tp) => {
  return { type: UPDATE_EMAIL, phone: id, uid: uid, tp: tp };
};
```

**Create Store**

```
function Root() {
  const [tkn, updateTkn] = useState("");
  const [type, updateType] = useState("");
  
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: credReducer,
  });

  const store = createStore(rootReducer);
  store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("in subscribe");
    console.log(store.getState().auth);
    updateType(store.getState().auth.tp);
    updateTkn(store.getState().auth.phone);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {tkn === "" || tkn === null ? (
          <Auth />
        ) : type === "doctor" ? (
          <Doctor />
        ) : (
          <Vendor />
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

**Fetching Store Value**

```
function Home() {
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  console.log("in home");
  console.log(auth);

  return (
    <View style={styles.box}>
      <Ucard />
    </View>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

and finally the output getting from the above block
enter image description here
[Home console log Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fM80.png)

Comment: You need to move your store creation to index.js and  I didn't see any update of your state in redux.

Comment: what are the outputs of the console.logs? I assume it logs multiple times, once before the update and ones after.

Comment: Why do you have the state from redux duplicated in your root component?

Comment: This whole setup is very strange. Are you following some tutorial for this? I would recommend reading the react-redux documentation and following the official tutorial to understand how to set the store up correctly https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be kept outside of the component. Let's say you update the `tkn` or `type` state then the function will rerun and again new store and root reducer will be created.

Store will be created with the initial state again and not the updated state.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: credReducer,
  });

  const store = createStore(rootReducer);
  store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log("in subscribe");
    console.log(store.getState().auth);
    updateType(store.getState().auth.tp);
    updateTkn(store.getState().auth.phone);
  }, []);
```

Comment: As soon as I moved my rootReducer and createStore outside my return function, it worked and the error was resolved. But i wonder whats the difference in declaring the them inside or outside the return function?

Comment: As you have defined a functional component. Whenever a component goes through a rerender all the variables inside it are reassigned. They are not preserved across rerenders like your state. To overcome this problem either you can use `React.useRef()` When data is stored within useRef() it is maintained across rerenders or simply declare the variable outside the component. So now as you move the store and reducer outside the component they are not being initialized again and again whenever component rerenders. So original store is maintained.